# Component's property validator using value of other properties in the same component

Tags: vue.js

A component's property can have a validator function.

Within this component's property (say `propA`), I want to use another property's (`propB`) value but I cannot simply get `this.propA`. How do I go about doing so?

Code sample:

```
props: {
    propA: String,
    propB: {
        type: Object
        validator: function(){
            switch(this.propA){ // "this" is undefined!!
                case 'A':
                    // Do something
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    // Do something else
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling you want to be using a computed property here. What's your goal and why do you feel this belongs in prop validation?

Comment: The component has multiple subtypes, each with slightly different properties. I want to know which type (propA) it is to validate if the properties exists. I placed these variable properties under "propB".

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the logic you'd have in the switch? I get the feeling you'd want something more like: ` computed: { subType() { switch(this.propA) { ... } }`.

Comment: For example an ad system where, there's a banner type and text type. If it is banner type, the property "image" must exist. If it's text, the property "headline" must exist.

Comment: I'd probably have two different components in that case. You can do like `<component :is="ad.type"></component>` and when they require the same type of functionality you can use mixins.

Comment: I do have separate ad components and this is a parent component that loads the sub ad-types. It's this way because the user can change the ad-type within the component -- so the change has to be handled by a common parent. But yes, mixins are a good idea for shared functionality that I haven't used. I am currently working around this issue by only validating properties on the sub components.